# biblatex and \fullcite: dot at the end is missing

Tags: biblatex, fullcite

Hej,

I am using `\fullcite` to print the bibliography entry within the text. There, I am missing the final dot (here after the year) as it correctly appears in the list of references with `\printbibliography`.

I would like to have that final dot when using the `\fullcite` command.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Trzesniowski:2011,
    address = {Wiesbaden},
    author = {Trzesniowski, M.},
    edition = {3},
    publisher = {Vieweg-Teubner},
    subtitle = {Handbuch mit praktischen Konstruktionsbeispielen},
    title = {CAD mit CATIA V5},
    year = {2011}}


\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{Trzesniowski:2011}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite} {\usebibmacro{prenote}} {\usedriver {} {\thefield{entrytype}}\addperiod} {\multicitedelim} {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. (anyway, a lot of code for a period...)

Answer (score 0):

An easy but less sophisticaded solution would be to simply put a fullstop behind your command like `\fullcite .`, which should result in just the same thing except it's way less elegant than scd's solution:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Trzesniowski:2011,
    address = {Wiesbaden},
    author = {Trzesniowski, M.},
    edition = {3},
    publisher = {Vieweg-Teubner},
    subtitle = {Handbuch mit praktischen Konstruktionsbeispielen},
    title = {CAD mit CATIA V5},
    year = {2011}}


\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{Trzesniowski:2011}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which should look like:
[image: Printed example]

Answer (score 0):

The period at the end of a bibliography entry is `\finentrypunct` and generally generated by a call to the `\finentry` macro in the `finentry` bibmacro.

`biblatex` explicitly does not set `\finentrypuntc` in `\fullcite`. This makes it slightly easier to deal with multiple citations in one `\fullcite` and it gives the user full control over the following punctuation.

Generally speaking, I think `\fullcite` should be used sparingly, so I'm wondering what the exact use case here is. Maybe there are more elegant methods that avoid an explicit `\fullcite` altogether and already come with the desired period or make it easier to get the period.

The standard definition of `\footcite` can be found in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 2157-2163 in v3.18b)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/868b79fecb7998742eae53d2f81bb637453ceaf7/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2157-L2163). I would add a `\finentry` (which typesets the `\finentrypunct`) as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \finentry}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem

\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```